# Is there a native function or plugin to allow admins to email all users?

Tags: users, plugins, emails, function

I want to be able to provide the admin with a function so that they can email all registered users of the site.

Is there a native function or plugin that would make this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Natively, there is no direct way to do this. It is possible, however, to easily create this functionality with a plugin...

1. Build an
   [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements)
   which will return a list of all users. Organize that data into a
   batch (or multiple batches) of recipient email addresses.
2. Use the
   [EmailService](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/emailservice) API
   to generate an email to your selected recipients.

Depending on your specific plans, some other small "in between" steps may be required to suit your individual needs.

Answer (score 8):

Currently there isn't a native function to do this.

The only plugin that I know of that can do this, is [Sprout Email from Barrel Strength Design](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email).

---

**EDIT:**

I just released a plugin called [Craft-Mailer](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-Mailer) which does what you are looking for.

Comment: Amazing! I look forward to trying it out. Many thanks.